# 404 on github release download using java

Tags: java, github, httpurlconnection, github-release

Why am I getting a 404 here, while downloading a **private** repo release artifact.

```
URL url = new URL("https://github.com/anandchakru/private_repo/releases/download/rel_v1/artif-3.0.jar?access_token=myaccesstoken");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());  //404
```

and not here, while downloading a **public** repo release artifact?

```
URL url = new URL("https://github.com/anandchakru/fr/releases/download/1.0/fr.jar");
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());  //200
```

**Note:** I'm able to download `https://github.com/anandchakru/private_repo/releases/download/rel_v1/artif-3.0.jar?access_token=myaccesstoken` (in an incognito/provate_mode browser).

Comment: Do you have access to the private repo?  Have you tried putting those urls into a browser? what happens?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the private repo.
Browser (in incognito mode, which means without my login) is able to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended doing the following:

1. Add header `Accept: application/json`
2. Hit `https://api.github.com/repos/anandchakru/private_repo/releases/assets/<asset_id>?access_token=myaccesstoken` to fetch the artifact.

**Code**:

```
URL url = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/anandchakru/private_repo/releases/assets/<asset_id>?access_token=<token>");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
ReadableByteChannel uChannel = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream foStream = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/username/artif-3.0.jar");
FileChannel fChannel = foStream.getChannel();
fChannel.transferFrom(uChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
uChannel.close();
foStream.close();
fChannel.close();
System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
```

Don't forget to close the foStream & uChannel.

Comment: In case the deprecated method message appears:

1. - Remove ?access_token=<token> from your URL

2.- Just add:

connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                    "token YOUR_TOKEN");